# Is it allowed to overload function with parameters that differs by top-level const-ness?

Tags: c++

I was confused that the compiler allowed overloading with only top-level const-ness when I test below code:

```
    void foo(int);
    void foo(const int);

    int main() {
        return 0;
    }
```

And here is the compilation result:

```
g++ -O0 testoverloading3.cpp -lm -o testoverloading3 -g -Wall -lpthread -std=c++11

Compilation finished at Wed Jul  9 15:45:35
```

This contradicts my understanding that top-level const-ness only shall not be overloaded. 
Was I missing some setting here?

Comment: Those are just declarations; try defining a body for each, and you'll get a different compilation result...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Is it true that a function/variable can be declared many times but defined only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler considers these two declarations

```
void foo(int);
void foo(const int);
```

as declarations of the same function.

According to the C++ Standard

> — Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence
>   of const and/or volatile are equivalent. That is, the const and
>   volatile type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when
>   determining which function is being declared, defined, or called

Comment: Is it true that a function/variable can be declared many times but defined only once?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thx for advice. A quick follow up: I tried out another duplicated declaration `int get(); double get();` but got warnings.

Comment: @user3792254 Inline functions can be defined several times. You include their definitions in each translation unit.

Comment: And, obviously, the answer to OP's question is: no, it's not allowed because they won't be overloads. They would be two definitions of the same function, hence violating the One Definition Rule.